# Ruby on Rails: How do I pass @variables to an iframe? (Goal: Sandboxing part of a page)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, i figured, that I'd have to do this with the URL, rather than rails magic, cause I haven't found anything on iframes and rails...

```
<iframe src="/content_container/<%@object.id%>?page=<%@page%>" width="665" height="85%" frameborder="0">
```

but... when i get an error: it show this

```
Request

Parameters:

{"page"=>""}
```

Any ideas?
or a better way?

My ultimate goal is to sandbox the js and CSS for an object, apart from the rest of the page... so i figured an iframe would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `=` signs:

`<%=@object.id%>?page=<%=@page%>`

Answer (score 0):

URL or session, there's no other (straightforward) way to pass data between two requests (which is what, in effect, you're dealing with here).

(I am using "session" broadly here - any permanent or semi-permanent storage using user's unique identification as a key; and I also incorrectly include POST parameters into the URL method; but you know what I mean.)